# Cable Internet connectivity Problem?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, internet

I just got Internet cable from Time Warner/ [EarthLink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EarthLink). For some reason I tried everything that Time Warner and Earthlink techs told me to do but nothing seems to work. I still can't connect to the Internet. For some reason they think it's the IPv4 address since it begins with 169. I did everything the told me to 8 times, but they both give me the run around tell me it's the other's fault. How can I fix this once and for all?

I have no router.

I use cable to connect to the Internet.

Windows Vista

Cable broadband.

Comment: right, HOW do you connect to the internet? which Operating system are you using. did you get a static IP address from your ISP?

Comment: (tagged windows based on http://superuser.com/questions/32167/how-to-reset-my-ip-address-help)

Comment: cable as in Cable Broadband or cable as in: i have a cable plugged into my computer? and if so, where is the other end of said cable plugged into?

Comment: see, in order for us to help you here we need as much information as possible, the type of your internet connection is rather irrelevant, what i want to know now is, whether you're using a wired or a wiredless connection. your IP address is provided by a Router (you don't have one?) or a cable modem. now how do you connect to this device?

Comment: right, where is the other end of your network cable plugged in? you obviously do have another computer connected to the internet now since your posting here.

Answer (score 1):

A 169.x.x.x IP address is assigned to a computer by the operating system when it cannot get an IP address from the DHCP server (e.g. the router).

There are many possible causes, e.g. faulty cable or NIC, router DHCP disabled.

We need more input on the matter.