# How To Reset My Ip Address Help?

Tags: windows-vista, networking, ip-address

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cable Internet Connectivity Problem?](https://superuser.com/questions/32160/cable-internet-connectivity-problem)

I tried to reset my Ip address through command prompt but I keep getting The requested operation requiress elevation what does this mean?

Now when I try to reset my IP address i get the following error the rpc server is unavailable what does this mean and how do I bypass this?

Comment: please stick to your original thread: http://superuser.com/questions/32160/cable-internet-connectivity-problem

Comment: @Molly : if it's a different question, it should be asked in a different "thread". So, good in this case.

Comment: right, let us 'renew' the IP address then :)

Comment: Personally I think you will get much better assistance by calling your service provider. This question is becoming extremely hard to maintain. Also adding further information distracts from the original question and invalidates any answers already made.

Answer (score 2):

You need to load cmd with elevated privileges. Right click on the executable, and click `run as administrator`.

Comment: Damn, beat me to it!

Answer (score 2):

1. Click **Start**
2. Type **cmd** and press **CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER**.

This will run an elevated command prompt and let you do what you need to do.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to [UAC (User Access/Account Control)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) On Windows Vista / 7.

Click start, then in search (instead of run) type cmd. You should see either cmd or command prompt come up in the search results above. Right click on it and click on "Run as Administrator" then click yes on the allow box, and you should be able to do what you want.

[image]

However, if you are just doing

```
ipconfig /renew
```

and the lease has not expired, it is highly likely that you will get the same IP.

Even if it has expired, unless someone else has it, it is likely you will get it.